# Regex.Replace with Placeholder

Tags: c#, regex

```
string output = @"D:\C_Drive\Desktop\z3-str\Z3-str.py";
            output = output.Replace(@"\", "/");
            output = Regex.Replace(output, @"(\w):/([^\\]*)", "/cygdrive/$(1)/$(2)");
```

For the above code, I expect the output to be

```
/cygdrive/D/C_Drive/Desktop/z3-str/Z3-str.py
```

but it gives me

```
/cygdrive/$(1)/$(2)
```

What is the problem

Comment: Use $1 and $2 backreferences, remove the parentheses.

Comment: And remove slash before first backreference.

Comment: Removing backslash does not seem necessary. But the last negated character class can be replaced with `.*`

Comment: Does this need to be a regex? Seems like path manipulation APIs would get the point across better, and be more robust.

Comment: I have the following in my `fstab` file: `none /mnt cygdrive binary,posix=0,user 0 0`, this would break your code which assumes the `/cygdrive`.  path - you should rather use `cygpath` or link to the cygwin dll.

Comment: Don't have time to compose an answer right now, but basically: strip the drive letter, split the rest of the path around the backslash, join it with `/`, prefix with `"/cygdrive/"+driveLetter`

Answer (score 1):

The reason the backreferences do not work is that you enclosed the IDs with parentheses. You can enclose them with braces to remove any ambiguity, but since you have just 2, you do not need them.

Just use `$1` and `$2`: `/cygdrive/$1/$2`.

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/xXOjpR)

Since you replace all `\` with `/`, you may also use `.*` instead of `[^\\]*` (you do not have any `\` any longer, thus you just match the whole rest of the string):

```
output = Regex.Replace(output.Replace("\\", "/"), @"(\w):/(.*)", "/cygdrive/$1/$2");
```

[Another demo](http://ideone.com/q6PtXj)